# How to reference the submit button in a jqGrid modal form

Tags: jqgrid

How do I reference the submit button?  I am trying to set the focus on the submit button when a certain field is exited.

Here's an example of my approach:

```
  dataEvents:[{
      type:'blur',
      fn: function(){
          $('#add').focus();
      }    
  }]
```

Have also tried $('#submit').focus();

Note: This button is the Add button of the Add New Record modal form of jqGrid

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the focus after the blur via a

```
$('#sData').focus();
```

Comment: good show, Mark.  is there a list of the various ids of the jqGrid elements?

Comment: No, but Firebug or one of it's equivalent is your friend when it comes to a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add id in submit button and try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").focus();
});

<input type="submit" value="u" name="submit" id="submit"/>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I didn't actually build this button.  It's built by the jqGrid.  To be clear, this is the Add button of the Add new record modal form.  I will edit my question to be more explicit.